# Create fat client (RIA) with HTML - controlled environment

Tags: asp.net, html, apache-flex, rich-internet-application

I realize that this question can start a discussion but that's really not my intention. We've created a Flex Application to take tests from candidates. The advantage of the Flex Application is that all state can be stored in the application running in the browser of the client. Things like time limits, navigation, scoring, ... can all be handled within the application without us having to worry about a back button for instance. Even running the app offline with Adobe Air isn't that hard.

My question now is if such an application could easily be made with HTML, Javascript, Ajax, ... ? The reason I'm asking is because an application in HTML would be much easier to distribute on Mobile devices for instance. Also, our domain model for instance is mostly implemented in AS3 (Flex) so using it along the server side means porting it to C#.NET. (with two codebases as a result).

Answer (score 1):

Look at any good MVC toolkit, you will easily be able to handle this. Castle project is good as is Microsoft MVC, both of which allow you to choose from a variety of view engines to handle the actual page rendering thereby allowing you to choose the most 'mobile efficient' engine...

As for the technicalities, you would store all persistent data in a server session object.